# $\mathcal{L}(\ell_2,\ell_2)$ is not separable and a isomerty $T\colon\ell_\infty\to\mathcal{L}(\ell_2,\ell_2)$

Tags: functional-analysis

I have to prove that the operator $T\colon\ell_\infty\to\mathcal{L}(\ell_2,\ell_2)$ such  $T((a_j)_{j=1}^{\infty})((b_j)_{j=1}^{\infty})=(a_jb_j)_{j=1}^{\infty}$ is an linear isometry.

How can I show that $T$ is an isometry, $( ||T(b_n||)=||b_n|| )$

can I use this to show that $\mathcal{L}({\ell_2,\ell_2})$ is not separable? I know that every normed separable space is 
isometrically isomorphic to a subspace of $\ell_\infty$ so I have to prove that $T$ is not a bijection. Is this true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

1. Bound $\|T(a)(b)\|_2$ in terms of $\|a\|_\infty$ and $\|b\|_2$.
2. What does $T(a)$ do to the "standard unit vector" $e_j$?
3. $\ell_\infty$ contains an uncountable set $S$ such that $\|s-t\|\ge 1$ for all $s,t \in S$ distinct.

Comment: $||T(a)(b)||_2\leq||a||_\infty||b||_2$, thanks

Comment: did you mean what does $T$ to $e_j$?

Answer (score 2):

Your $T $ is definitely not a bijection, but you cannot use it as you want. The way to use it is that you simply get that  $\mathcal L (\ell_2,\ell_2) $ contains a non-separable subspace. A separable metric space cannot contain a non-separable subspace, so you get the non-separability.

For the first part, 
\begin{align}
\|Ta\|^2&=\sup\{\|Ta (b)\|_2^2:\ \|b\|_2=1\}
=\sup\{\,\sum |a_jb_j|^2:\ \sum|b_j|^2=1\,\}=\|a\|_\infty^2.
\end{align}

Comment: is $im(T)$ the non-separable subspace of which you speak?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the point of the exercise.